# Got two errors while uploading videos using youtube data api, Unknownpart and insufficient permission

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I need to upload video by using YouTube API.

**What I have done so far:**  Created app in our google account and enable YouTube data API. Also in scope I have set "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube".

I got a message that this is sensitive scope and Google will verify before publish.

Below are the questions:

1. How I can identify the correct scope for video publishing over youtube?
2. How much time google takes to verify scopes?
3. If I find correct scope for publishing then I can use it before verifying by Google, if Yes then how?
4. What is Part, sometime I got a error for unknownPart Bad request?

For now I got below error message when I use scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." } } ' in C:\myGuide\youtube-test\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 C:\myGuide\youtube-test\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 C:\myGuide\youtube-test\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 C:\myGuide\youtube-test\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->ru in C:\myGuide\youtube-test\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118